# Changing fontsize of word "References" in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm a beginner to latex, I was writing an article. At the end when adding references. I did:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}

Some bibitems here

\end{thebibliography}
```

After compiling, the word "Reference" appears in pdf, and it is too big in size. I want its font size to be 12pt. How can I do that?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Which solution will work in your case might depend on your documentclass and packages

Comment: The package used are \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
%\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{inputenc}
%\usepackage{authblk}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

Comment: Can you please make edit your question and make a *compilable* [mre], e.g. a small test document we can copy and paste to  reproduce your problem without having to guess which of the several documentclasses you are using?

Comment: please check your preamble for obsolete packages like `times`. You can get a list at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nag/nag.pdf

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments. Make sure your code is a [mcve]. If people can't reproduce the problem your question is likely to get downvoted and closed. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `titlesec` package, you can temporarily change the size of section headings:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

test

\begingroup
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries\selectfont}
\begin{thebibliography}{100}

Some bibitems here

\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```